# HTML email input type escapes string after @ symbol before being submitted

Tags: php, html, validation, email

When I have the input set like this:

```
<input type="email" name="email" maxlength="254" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
```

Because of the email type it escapes emails like "email@dómáín.cóm" to "email@xn--dmn-fla4d7a.xn--cm-5ja" **before** it's being submitted.

That's a problem for me, because I have a FormValidator class that sanitizes those characters, but when the email validator gets supplied something like "email@xn--dmn-fla4d7a.xn--cm-5ja" it returns as valid, because they are all valid characters.

Is there anything I can do to not make it convert it like that?

Or should I just not use the `type="email"` on the input at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html) doesn't say in detail what a browser should do with `type="email"`, so the validation process might [look different](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs.html). In other words: If you want to handle validation by yourself, `type="text"` would make more sense.